# Deploying a Go app with Imagemagick on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go, imagemagick

I've been trying to deploy a simple Go app with [imagick](https://github.com/gographics/imagick)
This requires `Imagemagick`. I've tried using the [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to install Imagemagick and run my app. This is how my `.buildpack` looks like:

```
https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick
https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
```

And this is the error I see on Heroku:

```
    Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 170, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (154/154), done.
Writing objects: 100% (169/169), 170.13 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 169 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick
=====> Detected Framework:
-----> Installing libpng 1.5.14
       Download completed
       Installation completed
-----> Installing imagemagick 6.8.2-3
       Download completed
       Installation completed
-----> Building runtime environment for imagemagick
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
=====> Detected Framework: Go
-----> Installing go1.3... done
-----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
# github.com/gographics/imagick/imagick
error: 'RemoveAlphaChannel' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'FlattenAlphaChannel' undeclared (first use in this function)
godep: go exit status 2

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

To git@heroku.com:philosoraptor-me.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [`image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/) package from Go's excellent standard lib instead of depending on `imagemagick`.

This also taught me a valuable lesson about looking for a solution as close to the problem as possible than trying to solve it with a tool that I'm most familiar with.

Comment: I have the same issue... but the image package requires different code than imagemagick no? Is there a way to get imagemagick to work?

Comment: @Lion789, yep you are right - both have different functionalities yet do some similar stuff. Fortunately for me, I was able use one of the functionalities to fit my requirements. I'm sorry I don't have a better answer at the moment. If I ever figure it out, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your local copy of gographics/imagick and doing `godep update gographics/imagick` ? The error `error: 'FlattenAlphaChannel' undeclared` seems to be coming from the library and not the buildpack

Comment: catsby, I tried running `godep update github.com/gographics/imagick/imagick`locally and I don't get any errors. I removed my local copy of imagick and tried as well.